# 2 Warnings during Hibernation which I'd love to resolve if possible

Tags: dual-boot, suspend, hibernate, 18.10

**This is Ubuntu 18.10 dual booted with Windows 10.**

When I attempt hibernation:

```
Tuxonice binary signature file not found.
```

While resuming hibernation:

```
[12525.238604] Bluetooth: Unable to create CMAC crypto context
```

The reason I want to resolve this "warning" is that it literally takes like 10 minutes to get an active screen. i.e It resumes very slow. And I hate to wait. If by resolving this issue I can get a faster active screen, than I'm all ears.

Note I use this command to Hibernate:

`sudo hiberate`

***Some output that might help this case:***

```
pranav@inspiron-5548:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       1.7Gi       4.9Gi       166Mi       1.2Gi       5.6Gi
Swap:          13Gi          0B        13Gi
pranav@inspiron-5548:~$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
RESUME=UUID=09e25397-4a2c-4fb0-a605-a7013eecb59c
pranav@inspiron-5548:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=aad43495-2006-41af-bcb1-f91673ac405e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=8A05-F7D6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=81af9024-5c08-4055-9423-12d0674fc723 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=09e25397-4a2c-4fb0-a605-a7013eecb59c none            swap    sw              0       0
pranav@inspiron-5548:~$ blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="EAD20314D202E4A3" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Ba" PARTUUID="aa5a9347-3807-406c-8a85-df356eb9be93"
/dev/sda2: UUID="8A05-F7D6" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="ee306771-48e7-4deb-9c8b-a23c5f0a9dc2"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="E0E07C6CE07C4B34" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f933de5f-d72a-48c0-918c-b1915e9700f2"
/dev/sda4: UUID="D8FA2AC3FA2A9DAE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="33885b82-b903-4ee7-9d91-8192f00f2209"
/dev/sda5: UUID="09e25397-4a2c-4fb0-a605-a7013eecb59c" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="349e80a2-b697-4a52-9e10-bceb4de75cf0"
/dev/sda6: UUID="aad43495-2006-41af-bcb1-f91673ac405e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="75f7f06e-fa94-4a66-b4dd-81ed2a5fe4a6"
/dev/sda7: UUID="81af9024-5c08-4055-9423-12d0674fc723" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="da56d350-933c-41ad-b29d-319c22d6d895"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop23: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop24: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop25: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop26: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop27: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop28: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop29: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop30: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop31: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop32: TYPE="squashfs"
```

> sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

```
pranav@inspiron-5548:~$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-14-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-14-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89946/discussion-on-question-by-prabesh-bhattarai-2-warnings-during-hibernation-which).